# Why when I try to download a PDF file in laravel, open a file with strange characters?

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-4

I have the follow code to download a PDF in laravel

**Controller**

```
public function doDownload($id){

        $servicio = Servicio::find($id);
        $array = explode('/', $servicio->RutaPDF);
        $path = '/home/web-apps/marsur/public/servicio/'.$array[1].'/ordedeservicio.pdf'; //array[1] contain a number

        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($path));   
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));
        flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
        $fp = fopen($path, "r");
        while (!feof($fp))
        {
            echo fread($fp, 65536);
            flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
        } 
        fclose($fp); 
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('servicio/download/{id}', array('uses' => 'ServicioController@doDownload'));
```

when I use `Postman` to test, this appear

[image]

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the specfic MIME type for a pdf:

```
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
```

On a side note, you could use [Laravel's downlod method](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses) that should take care of everything (it's smart enough to guess the MIME type correctly and provide the right headers), without you having to create all the headers manually:

```
return Response::download($filePath, $fileClientName);
```

You can also specify the headers manually as 3rd parameter, but everytime I used this to download a PDF it worked straight away, so it shouldn't be necessary.